# log4net change conf file path dynamicaly

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I need to change the conf file path depending on the environment.
In my Gobal.asaw.cs i have :

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

In my web.config :

```
 <add key="log4net.Config" value="conf/Log4netDev.config"/>
 <add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True"/>
```

In my web.Debug.config :

```
<add key="log4net.Config" value="conf/Log4netDev.config" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
<add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
```

In my web.Release.config :

```
<add key="log4net.Config" value="conf/Log4netRelease.config" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
<add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
```

So in my web.config, the log4net.Config value is same as in web.debug.config
With visual studio, if i run in debug, i can find my logFile where it's supposed to be, everything is ok.
If i run in release, no log file...

I've tried to replace the log4net.Config value in web.config with the value i have in web.release.config, and now : when i run project in Release i have my log file and not in debug anymore.
What i understand is this only work when the value is in the web.config

Comment: Web Config Transformation does not work, when you run your application with Visual Studio. It means that works default settings inside web.config <add key="log4net.Config" value="conf/Log4netDev.config"/>.

Comment: Crap... Thx anyway =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add config transformations for a custom config file in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735132/how-to-add-config-transformations-for-a-custom-config-file-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

***Why not change it programmatically*** ?

```
    var loggingConfigurationFile = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled ? "conf/Log4netDev.config" : "conf/Log4netRelease.config";
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(loggingConfigurationFile));
```